# What's the best way to get data from the app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config

For a long time I used:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnectionstring"].ConnectionString
```

to get the connection string from the app.config file

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="sqlconnectionstring" connectionString="Data  Source=ggg;Initial Catalog =DB;User ID=sa;Password=sa" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Lately I found that I canget the string using

```
global::myProj.Properties.Settings.Default.sqlconnectionstring;
```

1. What is the difference?
2. Can I access a key under appSetting?
3. How come I don't need to import System.Configuration?

Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `global::myProj.Properties.Settings.Default.sqlconnectionstring;` stuff is generated by the settings designer in Visual Studio.

The settings can be found in the solution explorer under Properties->Settings.settings, typesafe wrapper methods are automatically generated for all your properties defined in the settings designer.

This only works for settings defined in the settings designer (connection strings are automatically added to the settings designer).

**Edit**, to answer your specific questions

1. The second is a generated wrapper of the first one.
2. Nope, but if you create your own settings in the settings designer they are stored in another section called "applicationSettings".
3. The import (or rather used by fully qualified name is done in the generated wrapper class).

Comment: You can press [F12] on `sqlconnectionstring` to see how the wrapper is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mentioned type `global::myProj.Properties.Settings.Default` is generated for you by Visual Studio, if you are using a setting for your project. It uses low level infrastructure to gain access to the app.config.

Note that the namespace System.Configuration is available even when you don't reference the System.configuration.dll. It's because several types of the System.Configuration namespace reside in several other assemblies (e.g System.dll), which are referenced by default.

`ConfigurationManager` resides in the System.configuration.dll. Thus if you want to use it, you'll need to reference that assembly.

If you need access the appSetting section in the app.config file, I think you need to stick to the `ConfigurationManager`. If you are starting a new application I would recommend using Visual Studio's support for settings and access your settings via the types provided in the `global::myProj.Properties` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

using `global::` is only really required when you need to distinguish between namespaces for a particular method or variable.  Further information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx)

For C# it is far easier to use `Properties.Settings.Default` to access properties in your config file.